# How to reuse put-list-attributes variables in Spring Tiles 2.2 + Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm developing a web-app using Spring 4 MVC, Apache Tiles 2.2.2 and Spring Roo to generate some boilerplate code. I have my views.xml (where I have the tiles configuration) file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="form" name="check/readCheck">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/check/readCheck.jspx" />
        <put-list-attribute name="cssList" cascade="true" >
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/ionicons.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/AdminLTE.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/datetimepicker/datepicker3.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/iCheck/all.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
    </definition>

    <definition extends="form" name="check/createCheck">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/check/createCheck.jspx" /> 
        <put-list-attribute name="cssList" cascade="true" >
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/ionicons.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/AdminLTE.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/datetimepicker/datepicker3.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/iCheck/all.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" />
            <add-attribute value="/resources/css/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

As you can see, I have repeated the **put-list-attribute** section twice.

What I want to know is **if there's a way to define once the dependencies and reference them as much as needed?**

I found this link: [the ultimate view — Tiles-3](http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/) but I can't see clearly if those patterns could help me.

Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Either definition inheritance or injected definitions (as described in article) might be what you're after?

Comment: I was thinking more in assigning the dependencies in a variable (in XML) and then use the var below.

Comment: not that i know of. you can include definitions. check out the docs on http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a default template and then extend your template as follow:

```
<tiles-definitions>   
    <definition name="app.base" template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Not Found" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/templates/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="navbar" value="/WEB-INF/templates/navbar.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/templates/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets">
              <add-attribute value="/static/css/bootstrap.css" />           
        </put-list-attribute>
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts">
              <add-attribute value="/static/public/js/bootstrap.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>   
    </definition>
    <definition name="yourpage" extends="app.base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Your Page" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/yourpage.jsp" />
        <put-list-attribute name="javascripts" inherit="true">
              <add-attribute value="/static/protected/js/newjavascript.js" />
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Do you know if you can inherit an inherited definition? I mean, generate grandchild

Comment: yes of course! For instance you can just extend yourpage with another definition. Also be careful that I put `inherit="true"`